# how to input several words and make words into an array

Tags: java

I am a student and a new fish in Java.I know my question is low..still can not make it out..except the answer,is there any suggestions to coding?this questiin is mostly about I/O and String class,however,I could not find a right function and combine them..
thanks for help!

Comment: What format are you inputting the words in? eg. `word1,word2,word3` or `word1 word2 word3`

Comment: would you mind show the two ways?

Comment: You can try googling the two things needed to accomplish this. 1) Reading input from stdin in Java 2) Declaring an array and inserting elements into it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `splitter` as the string that separates words in your input. For `word1, word2, word3` do

```
    String splitter = ", ";
```

Then you need to input the text into your program. One of the ways is

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // make sure to import java.util.Scanner
    String input = sc.nextLine();
```

Then create an array of words with

```
    String[] words = input.split(spiltter);
```